# Collecting data from Google Apps users' spreadsheets programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-fusion-tables, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

We have a number of Google Apps users, each of them has a non-public spreadsheet named 'XData' in their GDrive account. The Google Apps admin needs to be able to do the following:

1. Click one button that would collect specified data from users' spreadsheets and put it into a master spreadsheet on admin's account.
2. Click another button that would display the data from master spreadsheet to admin in a nice visual way.

What's the best way to implement such setup using Google tools (Fusion Tables and/or Admin SDK and/or Apps Script and/or Drive SDK and/or Spreadsheets API and/or etc)? The first step is optional if the second one can be accomplished without it.

Comment: 1.   Try.
2.   Try harder.
2.5  Realize that SO is not a freelancer site.
3.   Post what you have tried and it didn't work.
4.   Get answers

Answer (score 1):

## 1 and #2 can be done easily with apps script only if all the spreadsheets are shared with the script owner.

If they are not shared you can only do it with drive api and user delegation of permissions (see the drive api docs)

Comment: To ad to Zig's answer, if you use Drive SDK you will have a scope issue. Specifically, each user will need to grant full drive access to admin, ie. admin can see all Drive files. To get around that, you may want to have your DriveSDK app create the XData spreadsheet. Then you could get away with only granting drive.file access, ie. admin can ONLY see XData.

Comment: You missed the point of my comment. The issue is not the process of granting the scope, which as you say can be done via delegation. The purpose of my comment was to suggest a mechanism by which the app is only granted access to XData (/drive.file scope) as opposed to *all* of the user's files (/drive scope).